# Codeigniter redirect base_url to default controller

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

In my site, the base ur is

```
base_url = 'localhost/cl/'
```

I want to redirect to 'localhost/cl/index.php/welcome' when they enter 'localhost/cl/'. I used .htaccess file to redirect but it isn't work. How could I do this? this is what i used in .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 / http://localhost/cl/index.php/welcome
```

## update

i couldn't find any solution to fix this using htaccess. I put a if statement in my default controller that redirect me to desire page.

```
if(current_url() == base_url()) {
    redirect(base_url().'index.php/welcome/');
}
```

Thanks everyone for give me your valuable time.

Comment: Have you set it on the config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/cl/';`

Comment: Yes i set this on config. but i want to redirect when anyone type this on browser

Comment: same thing you can solve using `'rount.php'` in `config` folder without using `htaccess` file

Comment: @Ayyappaamara i couldn't find any way to redirect base_url, it works when ulr have controller or method name.

Comment: @aziz can you please share your config.php and route.php files? then i can give you perfect solution.

Comment: @Ayyappaamara " $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/cl/'; " and route .php is $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Comment: @aziz posted my code. please follow. it may helps you.

Comment: @Ayyappaamara very sorry brother, it doesn't work

Comment: Base url need to have scheme. Do not interpret documentation loosely. `http://localhost/ci/`. [Link](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L4-L26).

Answer (score 1):

routes.php can handle it.

**LINK**
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: there is no option to route base_url, i think when i have a controller or method, then I could use route to redirect or rewrite url

Answer (score 0):

Follow these step to solve your issue.

Add this code in **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|bootstrap|dist|plugins|css|js|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

In **config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].':'.$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].'/ci/';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

in **routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';// Your controller name as landing page.
```

If it not working means, you need to enable `mod_rewrite` in Apache

All the best.

Comment: i changed my code as per your instruction, but it didn't work.

Comment: It not redirecting, after entering 'localhost/ci' I am not redirecting to 'localhost/ci/index.php/welcome'

Comment: why `index.php` will appear in url? is `index.php` required in your project or requirement?

Comment: Yes brother, index.php is required,

Comment: i used this and mention in my question, it won't work. it generate a very long url :'(